# Compile Error: Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement

Tags: apex, visualforce, error-messages

I'm getting the above said error and I have included a `return` statement where ever an `if` statement has ended. The error is at the line `if(tripType == 'Start'){`

The code is given below.

```
public PageReference createTrip(){
            Trip_Detail__c trip = new Trip_Detail__c ();
            PageReference vfPage = new PageReference('/Trip_Details');
            if(tripType == 'Start'){
                trip.Start_Trip_Location__Latitude__s = latitude;
                trip.Start_Trip_Location__Longitude__s = longitude;
                trip.Type__c = 'Start';
                trip.from__c = searchTrip;
                trip.To__c = searchTerm;
                trip.Trip_Sheet_Number__c = tripNumber;
                trip.Start_Time__c = String.valueOf(System.Now());
                //tripList.add(trip);
                if(searchTrip == NULL || searchTerm == NULL || tripNumber == NULL){
                    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Trip Sheet Number, From Location and To Location have to be filled.');
                    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                    return null;
                }
                insert trip;
                tripId = trip.Id;
                return vfPage.setRedirect(true);
            }
            else if(tripType == 'Stop'){
               // Trip_Detail__c trip = new Trip_Detail__c ();
                checkTrip();
                trip.Stop_Trip_Location__Latitude__s = latitude;
                trip.Stop_Trip_Location__Longitude__s = longitude;
                trip.Type__c = 'Stop';
                trip.Id = tripId;
                trip.Stop_Time__c = String.valueOf(System.Now());
                // tripList.add(trip);
                update trip;
                tripId = NULL;
                return vfPage.setRedirect(true);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the below code

```
public PageReference createTrip(){
            Trip_Detail__c trip = new Trip_Detail__c ();
            PageReference vfPage = new PageReference('/Trip_Details');
            if(tripType == 'Start'){
                trip.Start_Trip_Location__Latitude__s = latitude;
                trip.Start_Trip_Location__Longitude__s = longitude;
                trip.Type__c = 'Start';
                trip.from__c = searchTrip;
                trip.To__c = searchTerm;
                trip.Trip_Sheet_Number__c = tripNumber;
                trip.Start_Time__c = String.valueOf(System.Now());
                //tripList.add(trip);
                if(searchTrip == NULL || searchTerm == NULL || tripNumber == NULL){
                    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Trip Sheet Number, From Location and To Location have to be filled.');
                    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                    return null;
                }
                insert trip;
                tripId = trip.Id;
                //return vfPage.setRedirect(true);
            }
            else if(tripType == 'Stop'){
               // Trip_Detail__c trip = new Trip_Detail__c ();
                checkTrip();
                trip.Stop_Trip_Location__Latitude__s = latitude;
                trip.Stop_Trip_Location__Longitude__s = longitude;
                trip.Type__c = 'Stop';
                trip.Id = tripId;
                trip.Stop_Time__c = String.valueOf(System.Now());
                // tripList.add(trip);
                update trip;
                tripId = NULL;
                //return vfPage.setRedirect(true);
            }
    return vfPage.setRedirect(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a return statement right at the end.

If `tripType` was equal to `'Bob'` then it wouldn't match either block and the method wouldn't return a value. This is what the compiler is complaining about.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define return statement at the end of the method like below

```
public PageReference createTrip(){
            Trip_Detail__c trip = new Trip_Detail__c ();
            PageReference vfPage = new PageReference('/Trip_Details');
            if(tripType == 'Start'){
                trip.Start_Trip_Location__Latitude__s = latitude;
                trip.Start_Trip_Location__Longitude__s = longitude;
                trip.Type__c = 'Start';
                trip.from__c = searchTrip;
                trip.To__c = searchTerm;
                trip.Trip_Sheet_Number__c = tripNumber;
                trip.Start_Time__c = String.valueOf(System.Now());
                //tripList.add(trip);
                if(searchTrip == NULL || searchTerm == NULL || tripNumber == NULL){
                    ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Error: Trip Sheet Number, From Location and To Location have to be filled.');
                    ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
                    return null;
                }
                insert trip;
                tripId = trip.Id;

            }
            else if(tripType == 'Stop'){
               // Trip_Detail__c trip = new Trip_Detail__c ();
                checkTrip();
                trip.Stop_Trip_Location__Latitude__s = latitude;
                trip.Stop_Trip_Location__Longitude__s = longitude;
                trip.Type__c = 'Stop';
                trip.Id = tripId;
                trip.Stop_Time__c = String.valueOf(System.Now());
                // tripList.add(trip);
                update trip;
                tripId = NULL;

            }

            return vfPage.setRedirect(true);
}
```